# What API do source commands use in SFDX CLI?

Tags: metadata, dx, sfdx

Using the SFDX mdapi commands the CLI deploys using metadata API for files in MDAPI format. I get that.

Using SFDX source commands uses what API? I know it is source format and you can do deployments without package.xml etc, but behind the scene what is being used to deploy changes?

Does a source deploy command use metadata API under the hood?